# Sending a JSON encoded PHP variable to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to send a PHP variable to my javascript.  In order to do this, I encode the php variable with json, send it to my view with my controller, use it as a value in a hidden html form, and then pull the value with js, using parseJSON to get the final product.

**HTML** (I'm using laravel, the brackets are equivalent to php tags):

```
<input type="hidden" id="js-helper-artist-likes" name="js-helper-artist-likes" value="{{$artist_likes}}">
```

**JS**

```
var artist_likes = $('#js-helper-artist-likes').val();
    console.log(artist_likes);
```

In the page source, I see that the value is populating with the json string, but when I print it to the console from my js like the above, all that is showing is: `[{`

I am not sure why this is.

I want to perform:

```
var artist_likes_decoded = $.parseJSON(artist_likes);
```

to get the decoded variable in JS, but this is impossible without the encoded string coming up correctly in the artist_likes variable in js.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you.

Comment: JSON format has to be in key:value pair. I think you json encoded variable is not in proper format. you should do like this array("name"=>$varable); json_encode it and then assign it to hidden tag.using $.parseJSON you will get value in proper format

Comment: can you show this in a code example in an answer?

Comment: also, the variable is an array

Comment: check below posted answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" id="js-helper-artist-likes" name="js-helper-artist-likes" value="{{ echo $artist_likes}}">
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding some more explanations

Comment: Neither of these answer are correct...I told you that I am using Laravel, and that is blade syntax (equivalent to <?php echo $artist_likes ?>), the $artist_likes is already json encoded.  If you look at the page source, the value is populating as a long json string.  My question was why is it being printed as [{ only when I pull it with .val in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="js-helper-artist-likes" name="js-helper-artist-likes" value="<?= json_encode($artist_likes) ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
      $yourVariable ="something";
      $arr = json_encode(array("name"=>$yourVariable));
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="js-helper-artist-likes" name="js-helper-artist-likes" value='<?php echo $arr; ?>'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var artist_likes = $('#js-helper-artist-likes').val();
console.log($.parseJSON(artist_likes));
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: any ideas why this is?

Comment: This did not answer the question.